# Conditional count of number of rows with value greater than the current one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Maybe a bit of beginner's question, but my mind is really stuck.

I have a dataframe with certain values in a column called x, split into two groups.

```
   x     group
1  1.7   a
2  0     b
3  2.3   b
4  2.7   b
5  8.6   a
6  5.4   b
7  4.2   a
8  5.7   b
```

My purpose is for each row, to count how many rows of the other group have a value greater than the current one. So to make it more clear, for the first row (group a) I am looking to find how many rows of group b are greater than 1.7 (the answer is 4). The end result should look like :

```
   x     group   result
1  1.7   a       4
2  0     b       3
3  2.3   b       2
4  2.7   b       2
5  8.6   a       0
6  5.4   b       1
7  4.2   a       2
8  5.7   b       1
```

I have several rows in the dataframe, so ideally I would also like a relatively fast solution.

Comment: what do you mean by several rows? 100 or 10 000? also only 2 groups in your real case?

Comment: I have approximately 130 000 rows. Only two groups, yes (a and b).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.searchsorted`:

```
df['result'] = 0

a = df.loc[df['group'] == 'a', 'x']
b = df.loc[df['group'] == 'b', 'x']

df.loc[a.index, 'result'] = len(b) - np.searchsorted(np.sort(b), a)
df.loc[b.index, 'result'] = len(a) - np.searchsorted(np.sort(a), b)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     x group  result
1  1.7     a       4
2  0.0     b       3
3  2.3     b       2
4  2.7     b       2
5  8.6     a       0
6  5.4     b       1
7  4.2     a       2
8  5.7     b       1
```

**Performance** for 130K records

```
>>> %%timeit
    a = df.loc[df['group'] == 'a', 'x']
    b = df.loc[df['group'] == 'b', 'x']
    len(b) - np.searchsorted(np.sort(b), a)
    len(a) - np.searchsorted(np.sort(a), b)

31.8 ms ± 319 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Setup:

```
N = 130000
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randint(1, 1000, N),
                   'group': np.random.choice(['a', 'b'], N, p=(0.7, 0.3))})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way. Based on `rank`ing in descending order the `x` values per group, and `merge_asof` df with itself, after exchanging the group name to merge a with the ranked values in b, vice versa.

```
# needed for the merge_asof
df = df.sort_values('x')

res = (
    pd.merge_asof(
        df.reset_index(), # to keep original index order
        df.assign(
            # to compare a with b in the merge
            group = df['group'].map({'a':'b', 'b':'a'}), 
            # rank descending to get the number of number above current number
            result = df.groupby('group')['x'].rank(ascending=False)),
        by='group', # same group first, knowing you exchange groups in second df
        on='x', direction='forward') # look forward on x to get the rank
      # complete the result column
      .fillna({'result':0})
      .astype({'result':int})
      # for cosmetic
      .set_index('index')
      .rename_axis(None)
      .sort_index()
)
print(res)
#      x group  result
# 1  1.7     a       4
# 2  0.0     b       3
# 3  2.3     b       2
# 4  2.7     b       2
# 5  8.6     a       0
# 6  5.4     b       1
# 7  4.2     a       2
# 8  5.7     b       1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the values and use masks to `cumsum` per the other group:

```
df2 = df.sort_values(by='x', ascending=False)
m = df2['group'].eq('a')
df['result'] = m.cumsum().mask(m).fillna((~m).cumsum().where(m)).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
     x group  result
1  1.7     a       4
2  0.0     b       3
3  2.3     b       2
4  2.7     b       2
5  8.6     a       0
6  5.4     b       1
7  4.2     a       2
8  5.7     b       1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty efficient, just one sort of all `x` and then just calculating cumsums

```
df2 = df.sort_values('x', ascending=False).reset_index()
df2['acount'] = (df['group'] == 'a').cumsum()
df2['bcount'] = (df['group'] == 'b').cumsum()
df2 = df2.fillna(0)
df2
```

at this point df2 looks like this:

```
    index   x   group   acount  bcount
0   5       8.6 a       0.0     0.0
1   8       5.7 b       1.0     0.0
2   6       5.4 b       1.0     1.0
3   7       4.2 a       1.0     2.0
4   4       2.7 b       1.0     3.0
5   3       2.3 b       2.0     3.0
6   1       1.7 a       2.0     4.0
7   2       0.0 b       3.0     4.0
```

now restore the index and choose `acount` or `bcount` depending on the group:

```
df2 = df2.set_index('index').sort_index()
df2['result'] = np.where(df['group']=='a', df2['bcount'],df2['acount']).astype(int)
df2[['x','result']]
```

final result

```
    x   group   result
index           
1   1.7 a       4
2   0.0 b       3
3   2.3 b       2
4   2.7 b       1
5   8.6 a       0
6   5.4 b       1
7   4.2 a       2
8   5.7 b       1
```

performance (on the same 130000 row test as @Corralien, not the same hardware obv)

```
65.4 ms ± 957 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not too different from Corralien's solution, but you can use broadcasting to do a check of all elements in group 'a' against all elements in group 'b' and count how many satisfy the condition. Then join the result back.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = df.loc[df['group'] == 'a', 'x']
b = df.loc[df['group'] == 'b', 'x']

result = pd.concat([
            pd.Series(np.sum(a.to_numpy() < b.to_numpy()[:, None], axis=0), index=a.index),
            pd.Series(np.sum(b.to_numpy() < a.to_numpy()[:, None], axis=0), index=b.index)])

df['result'] = result
```

---

```
     x group  result
1  1.7     a       4
2  0.0     b       3
3  2.3     b       2
4  2.7     b       2
5  8.6     a       0
6  5.4     b       1
7  4.2     a       2
8  5.7     b       1
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to use pandas' [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method.

```py
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: df[(df['group'] != row['group']) & (df['x'] > row['x'])].x.count(), axis=1)
```

Comment: with 100K rows, this method may be slow.

Comment: @Ben.T you're absolutely right